# How a store executed variable output into another variable, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my snippets:

```
create procedure sp (@pre nvarchar(50), @count nvarchar(50))
as
declare @preval nvarchar(500); 
declare @countval nvarchar(500);

select @preval = 'select '+ @prefix  + ' from tblc'
select @countval= 'select '+ @counter  + ' from tblc'

exec sp_executesql @preval,@countval
```

pre and count are a 2 input parameters which has gives "columnsname1" and "columnname2" which are dynamic.  I want to build a query/sp which gives me the value inside that particular columns and i want to store them in 2 different or single variable inside my sp.  Til now I'm getting column name as result which I don't want, I want value inside the particular column.nd also want that value in a 3rd variable! If any doubt let me know.

Comment: That procedure will not work: You have parameters `@pre` and `@count`, but use the names `@prefix` and `@counter` in your procedure. When you fix this it will work, at least it does so for me. Oh, and which RDBMS do you use? SQL Server?

Comment: This isn't how SQL is designed to work. Don't try to be clever and build generic code. You also can't store the output of a recordset in a counter

Answer (score 2):

Well... assuming that your example is pseudo code, and not expected to work verbatim, you could benefit from reading how sp_executesql works - noting that the second parameter is *not* a subsequent command to execute.

Having done that, you might try the following:

```
create procedure sp (@prefix nvarchar(50), @counter nvarchar(50)) 
as 
declare @preval nvarchar(500);  
declare @countval nvarchar(500);  
select @preval = 'select '+ @prefix  + ' from tblc' 
select @countval= 'select '+ @counter  + ' from tblc' 

declare @cmd as nvarchar(500);
set @cmd = @preval+';'+@countval 
exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

...and pray someone doesn't do this...

```
sp '1; delete',''
```

Personally, I would question *why* you feel the need to go down this road.

However, you will probably find that if you read up on sp_executesql, and look at the following example, you will find a way to get what you need. I'm guessing that the 'tblc' table only has a single row ?

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(4000)
declare @p1 as integer

set @sql = 'select @p1=count(*) from tblc'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@p1 int output', @p1 output

select @p1
```

Comment: +1 on the warning on SQL Injection and questioning **why** one would want to to this.